# 質問そのものにバッジをつけたら面白そう！

Tags: 討議, 機能の要求, バッジ

最近スタックオーバーフローをけっこう使っていて気づいたんですが質問そのものにバッジを付けられたら面白そうだと思いました。

たとえばコメントの応酬が活発になっているものには「白熱」というバッジをつけたり
たくさんの閲覧があるものの未回答の質問などには「難問」や「大いなる謎」というバッジをつけたり
長いあいだ未回答のものは「迷宮入り」というバッジをつけたり
長期間たくさんの人々に継続的に閲覧されて良い質問として投票されている質問には「殿堂入り」というバッジをつけたり
低評価と通報が著しい質問には「炎上」などのバッジをつけたり（これは不要かな？）

そんなことができそうです
すべての質問にバッジがつけられるわけではなく、ユーザーのバッジと同じく
サーバーのプログラムがある一定水準を満たした質問に対して自動でバッジを付与する仕組みです

面白そうだと思ったかたはいらっしゃいますか？
もしよろしければご意見をください

Comment: 現在でも[「いい質問」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question)のように質問に授与されるバッジはありますね。どの質問にバッジが授与されたかはこの一覧を見ないとわかりませんが…。

Comment: さらにいうと、[バッジ](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)の画面をみていれば、割とすでにたくさんのバッジがあるように思われます。

Comment: @unarist 「いい質問」はいい質問をしたことによって**質問者に**授与されるバッジですよね?

Comment: @masm はい、厳密には「質問ごとに質問者に授与されるバッジ」かと思います。なので質問からバッジが見たいということであれば機能不足ですが、質問の状態を基準に質問ごとに授与されるという点では、近いものかなと。

Comment: おーなんかいろいろな意見が聞けて楽しいですー

Answer (score 2):

unaristがコメントで言ったとおり、質問に関する質問がすでにあります：

> [image: バッジページ]

質問のバッジを増やすには投票が何よりも大事です。質問のバッジが欲しかったら、もっと投票しましょう！

Comment: OK!!!!!!!!!!!!!